# How to extract Response Body data with jMeter CSS Selector Extractor

Tags: jmeter

I'm aware there are a lot of those types of questions out there already. I have reviewed them, but it still didn't help me to solve my issue.

Lots of the other online examples have in the body
value = '123'
Name = 'Mr Test'

My one looks slightly different. It is probably very easy, but I need help to create my first CSS Selector Extractor:

This is how my response body looks.

[Response Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXqP8.png)

Can you help me with the CSS selector expression, please?
[CSS Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89f3x.png)

I would like to store the string starting with "CfD....." as a dynamic variable.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS Selector Extractor is for extracting data from [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/) responses with the help of [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php).

Your response data is not HTML, it's [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), therefore you won't be able to use it.

Consider switching to [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor), it allows executing arbitrary [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) queries to fetch the data you need from JSON responses.

[image]